# Why an error is thrown when checking length of an array element?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I cannot understand the difference between these two examples:

```
var arr1=[a,b,c,d,e];
console.log(arr1[0].length); /* undefined */
```

```
var str='a b c d e';
var arr2=str.split(' ');
console.log(arr2[0].length); /* 1 */
```

What is happening?

Comment: What type is a in arr1? A string?

Comment: The first block of code thrown an exception. Please create a [mcve]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In arr1 = [a,b,c,d] if the variable a,b,c,d are defined itrables (like: string, array) then it will arr[0].length will give defined output
example:

```js
let a = "ab"
let b = "b"
let c = "c"
let d = "de"
let arr1 = [a, b, c, d]
console.log(arr1[0].length)
// output: 2
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is not produced at second line but at the very first when you use `a` withtout quotes (`'`).

This is because the variable `a` has not been defined before...

Read carefully the error message:
`ReferenceError: a is not defined`

---

How to fix  that:

```
var arr1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'];
```

Answer (score -1):

This occurs because your first array is wrong,
Use quotes around your array items, you'll get the same result.

```js
var arr1=['a','b','c','d','e'];
console.log(arr1[0].length);
```